# What's wrong with this DFS solution?

Tags: python, algorithm

Problem Description:

You want to build a house on an empty land which reaches all buildings in the shortest amount of distance. You can only move up, down, left and right. You are given a 2D grid of values 0, 1 or 2, where:

Each 0 marks an empty land which you can pass by freely.
Each 1 marks a building which you cannot pass through.
Each 2 marks an obstacle which you cannot pass through.
For example, given three buildings at (0,0), (0,4), (2,2), and an obstacle at (0,2):

```
1 - 0 - 2 - 0 - 1
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
|   |   |   |   |
0 - 0 - 1 - 0 - 0
```

The point (1,2) is an ideal empty land to build a house, as the total travel distance of 3+3+1=7 is minimal. So return 7.

I solved this problem by BFS way. Then I want to solve it with DFS way but got stuck. Below is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def shortestDistance(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        rl, cl = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        builds = sum([col for row in grid for col in row if col == 1])
        dist, hit = [[0] * cl for _ in range(rl)], [[0] * cl for _ in range(rl)]

        def dfs(x, y, step):
            '''
            Wrong answer, it seems result dist alway keep the longest distance?
            '''
            if 0 <= x < rl and 0 <= y < cl and not visited[x][y]:
                visited[x][y] = True
                if grid[x][y] == 0:
                    dist[x][y] += (step + 1)
                    hit[x][y] += 1

                    dfs(x - 1, y, step + 1)
                    dfs(x + 1, y, step + 1)
                    dfs(x, y - 1, step + 1)
                    dfs(x, y + 1, step + 1)

        def bfs(x, y):
            '''
            works properly
            '''
            visited = [[False] * cl for _ in range(rl)]
            queue =[(x, y, 0)]
            while queue:
                k, m, step = queue.pop(0)
                for i, j in ((k - 1, m), (k + 1, m), (k, m - 1), (k, m + 1)):
                    if 0 <= i < rl and 0 <= j < cl and not visited[i][j]:
                        visited[i][j] = True
                        if grid[i][j] == 0:
                            dist[i][j] += (step + 1)
                            hit[i][j] += 1

                            queue.append((i, j, step + 1))
        for i in range(rl):
            for j in range(cl):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    # bfs(i, j) # this works properly
                    visited = [[False] * cl for _ in range(rl)]
                    dfs(i - 1, j, 0)
                    dfs(i + 1, j, 0)
                    dfs(i, j - 1, 0)
                    dfs(i, j + 1, 0)

        ret = float('inf')
        for i in range(rl):
            for j in range(cl):
                if grid[i][j] == 0 and hit[i][j] == builds:
                    ret = min(ret, dist[i][j])
        return ret if ret != float('inf') else -1

# expect 7
print Solution().shortestDistance([[1,0,2,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0]])
```

This is a kind of typical graph search problem. and usually could be solved in both DFS and BFS ways. Just can't figure out how to fix it in DFS way?

Answer (score 0):

Simply DFS is not intended to find the shortest path. With some backtracking and cautious marking and unmarking of visted nodes you could use it to find all paths reaching a given point and choose the shortest one but it is unnecessarily complex and way slower than BFS.